# Qual a diferença nos 3 tipos de variáveis e como elas se comportam no compilador?

Tags: c#, variáveis, método

Para questões de teste, fiz o seguinte código:

```
static int valor1 = 10 / 5;

static int valor2() => 10 / 5;

static int valor3 => 10 / 5;

public static void Main()
{
    Console.Write($"{valor1}\n{valor2()}\n{valor3}");
}
```

E a saída foi:

```
2
2
2
```

Ou seja, não houve diferença no resultado. Com isso, minhas duvidas são:

- Qual a diferença nos 3 tipos de variáveis apresentadas (se é que são variáveis)?
- Todos se comportam da mesma forma no compilador?

Funcionando [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wt8XGl).

Comment: Tudo me parece inteiro, porque você acha que  teriam diferenças?

Comment: @Articuno A forma da qual são criadas.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
static int valor1 = 10 / 5;
```

Isso é uma variável estática, provavelmente o compilador fará o cálculo e armazenará em área estática da memória o resultado.

```
static int valor2() => 10 / 5;
```

Aqui é um método estático, novamente pode haver uma otimização com o cálculo pronto armazenado em área estática, mas é menos provável, então sua invocação executará um algoritmo simples. Como é o método é interno e há garantias que ele não poderá ser acessado de fora é possível que o método seja otimizado e uma chamada ao valor direto seja colocado no lugar da chamada do método.

```
static int valor3 => 10 / 5;
```

Aqui é uma propriedade, ou seja um par de métodos de acesso (no caso terá apenas o `get`) que executará a operação quando for chamada. É possível que uma otimização seja feita como no método.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/FieldMethodProp.cs).

As otimizações não estão em especificação, é só uma possibilidade. Atualmente ocorre isto:

```
C..cctor()
    L0000: push ebp
    L0001: mov ebp, esp
    L0003: mov dword [0x1609da6c], 0x2
    L000d: pop ebp
    L000e: ret

C.valor2()
    L0000: mov eax, 0x2
    L0005: ret

C.get_valor3()
    L0000: mov eax, 0x2
    L0005: ret
```

Apenas retorna `2` nos 3 casos como o previsto. Mas achei que poderia ter mais otimização por ser um membro interno e não público.

[Veja no **SharpLab**](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LghgzgtgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoOBmFAJiQGEkBvHJalVANiQEsA7YJANzABsB7AJ1RIAvElTIA9EgCsWbDVoMWbTrz6EAFAEphAPlETps+WkWsO3fgSF6xSSTKo18ClABZaADi0VH86iR5mCB4uAFMAOgB1PkZgUPUAEgAichV+VABfAB1mVIs1LWzctL48DKTNIxoMnAygA===).

Comment: Não sei se tem muito a ver, mas vamos lá: Pelo que entendi na sua resposta, a forma mais otimizada é a primeira. Por quê? Pelo código do compilador que você deixou, não é o que aparenta, já que possui mais código.

Comment: Por isso que analisar código de forma superficial não dá certo. Ter mais código não significa que consome mais ciclos de processamento, não indica que haverá gargalos de transferência dos vários níveis de memória, etc. Neste caso aquele código até consumirá mais processamento, mas apenas uma vez antes de ser consumido e nunca mais, os outros códigos serão executados todas as vezes que tentar acessar o valor.

Answer (score 11):

```
static int valor1 = 10 / 5;    // Declaração de um campo.

static int valor2() => 10 / 5; // Declaração de um método estático utilizando membro de expressâo incorporada.

static int valor3 => 10 / 5;   // Declaração de uma propriedade utilizando membro de expressão incorporada.
```

A principal diferença é notada pelo uso de membros de expressão incorporada, que nada mais é do que açúcar sintático introduzido na versão 6 do C#.

O compilador converteria para o seguinte código (veja por você mesmo utilizando a ferramenta [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMDcCwAoEBmKAmCBhCBvJEhU0AbBAJYB2ALhAG4CGANgPYBO0EAvBNJAPQQArAkRIAkDDJVajVm3QAKAJTcAfLwHDREqRRr1m7NFw18IgkQSLXCqKABYIAWRV5bRQlhaUAziyYAUwA6AHU2cmpAxQASACJcOXZoAF8AHUpEowUVdMykthQUuOVRTxSkFKA==)):

```
private static int valor1 = 2;

private static int valor3
{
    get
    {
        return 2;
    }
}

private static int valor2()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Referências:

- [Campos](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields)
- [Método](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/methods)
- [Membro de expressão incorporada](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members)

Answer (score 6):

Na realidade você esta criando variáveis e métodos e atribuindo valores para elas de forma diferente.

Como na primeira.

```
static int valor1 = 10 / 5;
```

Aqui você declara a variável `valor1` como um inteiro e estática e atribuir o valor de uma função matemática para ela  `10 / 5`.

Na segunda;

```
static int valor2() => 10 / 5;
```

Você esta criando uma método e atribuindo um valor através de uma expressão (=>), veja que você não esta usando uma variável para acessar seu valor e sim chamando o método `valor2()`.

Na terceira;

```
static int valor3 => 10 / 5;
```

Você criar uma variável e atribuir o valor para ela através da expressão `=>`.

> Qual a diferença nos 3 tipos de variáveis apresentados(se é que são
>   variáveis)? Todos se comportam da mesma forma no compilador?

Conforme mostrado acima essas são as diferenças.

> Todos se comportam da mesma forma no compilador?

Não, como especifiquei cada uma tem um comportamento diferente perincipalmente a segunda as outras tem a forma como o valor foi atribuído.

Comment: Marconcilio, essa sintaxe não é de expressões lambda. Veja https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members

Comment: @mercador, editei.